# На чем эффективнее писать?

Tags: любой-язык, теория, кроссплатформенность, планирование

```
Критерии проекта таковы: 
1) ОС Linux, Windows
2) Desktop
3) Максимально гибкая графика (анимация по минимуму)
4) Работает как клиент, сильно великих расчетов нет, все производится на 
сервере.
```

Вопрос философский - какую технологию выбрать для эффективной работы? Текущие знания не имеют значения.

За эффективностью имеется в виду скорость работы программы и затраты ресурсов.

Comment: Ставлю плюс, но скорее всего закроют подобный вопрос.

Comment: «скорость работы программы и затраты ресурсов» — а есть ещё какие-то варианты помимо C и ассемблера?

Comment: Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа **перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ**, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Comment: @Kromster мне не нужен однозначный ответ. И дискуссии тоже как то не интересуют... просто надо знать на чем щас люди пишут кроссплатформу на десктоп. Хотелось бы увидить мнение человека, и хотя бы 1 предложение, почиму именно он "это" выбрал

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц по правилам SO, у вопроса должен быть однозначный правильный ответ. Вопросы-опросники тут не приветствуются. И даже если на это закрыть глаза, вопрос все равно слишком общий.

Comment: @Kromster а "общие" ответы тоже запрещены на сайте? я понимаю что программисты привыкли работать по алгоритму (даже при жарке яичницы)  но если у вас есть чего посоветовать, то напишите (если вам не трудно).... побульте немного человеком, и помогите новичкам. Я конешно могу открыть литературу....почитать...я в принципе так и сделал. Пока выбор пал на c++/python + qt  или electron. Вот теперь вы поделитесь своим опытом...может ваше предложение будет гораздо лучше

Comment: @Kromster на счет однозначного ответа....он вам даст балы...я не поверю что человек с 9,7к+ баллов гонится за этим. А варианты (пусть даже не будет правильного, т к его не может быть на 100%) возможно поставят людей на верный путь

Comment: @Kromster если вас так гнетет , что я пренебрег несколькими правилами SO ради передачи мнения от "гуру" к "новичкам", то для чего еще нужен этот сайт? я могу задать его в личку вам, или кому-либо другому, у кого есть ответы...я просто не знаю где я еще могу найти столько независсимых мнений опытных программистов.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц общие тоже нежелательны, вот цитата из флага к закрытию: *"Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. «Как задать хороший вопрос?» для прояснения ситуации."*. Ценность SO в том что это база конкретики, а не рассуждений и частных мнений. Касательно вопроса - выбирайте то что вам лучше знакомо.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц у тебя же есть достаточно репутации для общения в чате. Задай вопрос в общую группу, кто-то да и поможет. Вот у меня  буквально вчера тоже был вопрос, но с высокой вероятностью к закрытию, задал там, мне ответили и все супер :)

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос интересный, но явно под закрытие. Меня тоже интересовал вопрос мультиплатформенной разработки, так что попробую кратко изложить свои мысли по этому поводу.

**Вариант А. Производительность не нужна, важнее скорость разработки.**

Здесь однозначно что-нибудь из интерпретируемых языков - Ява, Питон, что-то еще. Не мой вариант, так что мало что могу сказать.

**Вариант Б. Производительность важна.**

Тут вариант один - C/C++, но встает проблема мультиплатформенной графики. Более-менее реальными выглядят два варианта:

**Qt** - огромная библиотека, хорошо документированная, с большим сообществом, в общем всем хорош вариант - НО! Ко всему этому прилагаются совершенно людоедские условия лицензирования. Этот вариант годится либо для опенсорсных поделок, либо для больших высокодоходных проектов с серьезным бюджетом на разработку. Если ваш проект где-то в середине, вся прибыль пойдет владельцам Qt.

**WxWidgets** - противоположный вариант. Никаких проблем с лицензией, но полный спектр прелестей опенсорса - мизерная и большей частью устаревшая документация (пресловутая "The Book" по WxWidgets), полное отсутствие саппорта, и т.д. и т.п.

В общем, выбор небольшой и непростой.

Comment: «Тут вариант один - C/C++» — Rust тогда уж

Comment: @andreymal а работу вы найдете изучив только Rust? Я думаю сначала лучше уж C/C++, а потом может быть там ещё и Rust  и прочие ЯП.

Comment: @SonicMyst слово «работа» употребляется в вопросе не в том смысле, который употребили вы. А C/C++ небезопасная переусложнённая дрянь, если уж сравнивать. Но популярная, это да

Comment: @andreymal думаю работа всех волнует в конечном счете, хотя если просто хобби, то да согласен пофиг можно любой подходящий под те критерии ЯП. Ну про современный C/C++ согласен, то что с ним сделали, а вот то что до версии 11 вполне себе норм, но если говорить о работе то там потребуют скорее всего и 11 и какие-то другие, ещё и STL и прочие вещи.

Comment: @SonicMyst современный C++ как раз более безопасный)

Comment: @andreymal я про безопасность ничего не говорил, и это кстати ещё вопрос, а вот по сложности написания кода и запутанности это...ппц.

Comment: @andreymal - я, возможно, не совсем точно выразился. Если важна просто производительность, то вариантов много, начиная с ассемблера. Но если нужно делать GUI, то выбор резко сужается. Я с Rust незнаком, но не уверен, что для него существует хорошая мультиплатформенная графика.

Comment: @freim с теми же Qt и WxWidgets у Rust действительно всё плохо (пока что). Но автор не уточнил, какую графику ему надо - на тех же OpenGL и Vulkan можно без проблем рисовать, например, довольно гибко в умелых руках :)

Comment: @andreymal, я не про разработку игр, для которой есть своя специфика. Речь про обычный графический интерфейс - окна, иконки, меню. Rust позволит быстро и с минимальными усилиями написать мультиплатформенный Notepad?

Comment: @freim сам Microsoft уже двадцать лет не может нормальный Notepad написать...)) Тем не менее автор ничего не говорил про «окна, иконки, меню», а OpenGL и Vulkan не ограничиваются только играми (тот же Qt может работать через OpenGL, раз на то пошло)

Comment: @freim что то на подобии гибкости c# wpf будет в полне достаточно ( т е если будет привязка к данным, то это тоже плюс)

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, если вас быстродействие шарпа устроит, то почему бы и нет, хороший вариант со всех сторон.

Comment: @устроило бы, если бы кроссплатформа была...но увы...а моно - как по мне - костыль